# Installing Windows 7 on System76

Tags: windows

I've seen the new All-In-One of System76, but I'm worried about a lot of enngineering software that is not compatible with Linux, such as Matlab, Solidworks, AutoCad, Autodesk Inventor, Altium Designer and 3Ds MAX. As well as the office stuff which I cannot depend on any other office-packages in other MS Office, especially for PowerPoint, Excel and Access.

I thought about Installing Windows alongside Ubuntu, and using Ubuntu for normal stuff while Windows for engineering computing. However, I'm afraid that Windows may face some problem with fully compatibility with the device.

Does somebody have any idea about this issue ?!

Will Windows work fine just like any Windows PC ?! Won't affect the work of Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure the System76 computers will work just fine with Windows. The parts in their computers are pretty standard it seems. There are even guides around for installing Windows alongside Ubuntu on these machines:
http://knowledge76.com/index.php/Windows_-_Add_MS_Windows_to_Your_System76_Machine

There are also drivers for Windows provided here: http://knowledge76.com/index.php/PanP4/PanP5

Windows 7/8 would most proably work out of the box just like on any other machine. I see no reason this should not behave like you want it to.

Comment: Windows may be harder to find drivers for, why not put your Windows VM inside Ubuntu?

Comment: 'Probably' and 'should' are just guesses and not helpful.

Comment: @nullsteph Comments on 3 year old answers are not that helpful either. And it was an educated guess that I don't really see any issues with. If you have something better to come with, please post your own answer and help out instead :)